# Passing parameters with a stored procedure to oracle from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a string: *“Sometimes,' said Pooh, 'the smallest things take up the most room in your heart.”*. When I insert this string into Oracle database using Oracle SQL Developer it works fine, but when I'm using ASP.net application I get this: *¿Sometimes,' said Pooh, 'the smallest things take up the most room in your heart.¿*

Could you help me?

Type of field in database - **NVARCHAR2**

Name of filed - **I_Comment**

Stored procedure from package:

```
PROCEDURE INSERTNEWSFLASH
(
i_StartTime DATE,
i_EndTime DATE,
i_Comment NVARCHAR2,
i_Priority NUMBER,
i_Type NUMBER,
i_AirlineCode VARCHAR2,
o_NewsFlashId out NEWSFLASH.NEWSFLASHID%type
);
```

Stored procedure in package's body:

```
PROCEDURE INSERTNEWSFLASH
(
i_StartTime DATE,
i_EndTime DATE,
i_Comment NVARCHAR2,
i_Priority NUMBER,
i_Type NUMBER,
i_AirlineCode VARCHAR2,
o_NewsFlashId out NEWSFLASH.NEWSFLASHID%type
) AS
BEGIN
  SELECT NEWSFLASHID_SEQ.nextval into o_NewsFlashId from dual;
  INSERT INTO NEWSFLASH
  (
    NEWSFLASHID,
    VALIDFROMDATE,
    VALIDTODATE,
    NEWSFLASHTEXT,
    NEWSFLASHPRIORITY,
    NEWSFLASHTYPE,
    AIRLINECODE
  )
  values
  (
    o_NewsFlashId,
    i_StartTime,
    i_EndTime,
    i_Comment,
    i_Priority,
    i_Type,
    i_AirlineCode
  );
END INSERTNEWSFLASH;
```

C# code:

```
public int Add(NewsFlashModel newsFlash)
    {
        using (IDataHelper dataHelper = dataHelperFactory.GetDataHelper(StaffTravelSettings.ConnectionStrings.ITravelDatabase))
        {
            dataHelper.AddParameter("i_StartTime", ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.Date, newsFlash.ValidFromDate);
            dataHelper.AddParameter("i_EndTime", ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.Date, newsFlash.ValidToDate);
            dataHelper.AddParameter("i_Comment", ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.String, newsFlash.NewsText);
            dataHelper.AddParameter("i_Priority", ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.Int32, newsFlash.Priority);
            dataHelper.AddParameter("i_Type", ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.Int32, (int) newsFlash.Type);
            dataHelper.AddParameter("i_AirlineCode", ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.String, newsFlash.AirlineCompanyCode);
            IDataParameter parameter = dataHelper.AddParameter("o_NewsFlashId", ParameterDirection.Output, DbType.Int32);
            dataHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("NEWSFLASH.INSERTNEWSFLASH");
            return Convert.ToInt32(parameter.Value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the database charset and collation?

Comment: ENGLISH_UNITED KINGDOM.WE8ISO8859P1  i can't change charset of this database. it is  requirement.

Comment: There is a `OracleDbType.NVarchar2` guess you should use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `OracleType.NVarChar2` instead of `DbType.String`